# Is it realistic to create gpu-intensive web apps using webgl running in the browser?

Tags: browser, gpu, webgl

I've been thinking about creating a snazzy game using webgl that runs in the browser, but I've noticed that despite having an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with 3gb of vram, I am only able to use up to 512mb of vram at a time. I believe this is because the browser is using my integrated gpu rather than my dedicated gpu. I've read about several people who have had the same issue and corrected it by doing some reconfiguring, but I wouldn't want users of my web app to have to worry about this if they too had a similar issue and needed more vram to run the app.

Is there an easy "fix" for allowing the browser to utilize the dedicated gpu without having to do any technical reconfiguration? Is this just an unfortunate issue of using the gpu in the browser? Or am I not understanding something fundamental about utilizing the gpu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WebGL you can ask the browser to use the discrete gpu by passing in `powerPreference: 'high-performance'` to `getContext` as in

```
const gl = someCanvas.getContext('webgl', {powerPreference: 'high-performance'});
```

You can check if it worked by using the `WEBGL_debug_renderer_info` extension if it exists

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {powerPreference: 'high-performance'});
const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
if (ext) {
  console.log(gl.getParameter(ext.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL));
  console.log(gl.getParameter(ext.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL));
} else {
  console.log('this browser does not support WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
}
```

If you don't pass in a `powerPerformance` setting it defaults to whatever the browser chooses. Most browsers choose the integrated GPU by default to save power.

As for GPU intensive, I'd say [Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/web/search/New+York+City,+NY,+USA/@40.71056852,-74.01141759,188.91010767a,1354.31404205d,35.00000054y,23.71118146h,75.89002709t,0r/data=CoEBGlcSUQolMHg4OWMyNGZhNWQzM2YwODNiOjB4YzgwYjhmMDZlMTc3ZmU2MhnDcpU4PFtEQCGYKr3bYYBSwCoWTmV3IFlvcmsgQ2l0eSwgTlksIFVTQRgBIAEiJgokCaSeNse8oTVAEbpFMXxloTVAGW4ttPZkwWPAIfmV4gJ2wWPA) is fairly intense?

---

## update

So as of 2020-07 the `powerPreference` option really only works on Dual GPU Macs. The good news is apparently [Microsoft is adding support to Chromium for Dual GPU Windows](https://twitter.com/gfxprogrammer/status/1282387095797895169).

Comment: I have a PC, a notebook in W11 with Iris as GPU-0, and MX-330 as GPU-1. I have a moderate load in my WebGL2 app, that could use GPU-1, but my browser always takes GPU-0 by default. Your above tip for 'high-performance' to switch to GPU-1 does not work, as your update remark states. Then, I  tried setting Graphics Options for the browser, via Windows Settings.. that does work for Google Chrome, but  to my surprise it did *not* work for Edge. The above option in the WebGL program would be very nice, you don't want to bother a client with going to Windows Settings !

Comment: My comment says it's being added. It doesn't say it's shipped. Chrome is also [adding support](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251724) for Windows

Comment: With Google Chrome, the Windows Graphics Setting works ! But  when publishing a nice animation online, you don't want to impose a) browser choice and b) Windows settings.. Just choose the fastest GPU. I assumed WebKit would be a proper standard, but alas..

Comment: Anyway +1 and thanks for the tip, I'll watch for it to appear in [these  docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API#webgl_2) some day.. or maybe [here](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cross-platform-issues.html) :)